# Audio not working for iOS devices

Tags: audio

After rendering an animation, the audio is only reproduced on Android devices, for iOS the video stay muted.

My audio files are on .wav format and render settings are as follow:

[image]

someone has gone through similar situation or know how to help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in my experience mp4 works well with ACC and AC3

Comment: thanks @wilks, this was really helpful! I used AAC for audio code and now it working perfectly for both platforms